# Error when I try to make a !ping command in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a !ping command but i keep getting this error when I do "node ." in vscode

const client = new Discord.Client();
^

```
ReferenceError: Discord is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\SpidBot\src\index.js:7:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

It says "Discord is not defined" which I dont know the meaning of, heres my code:

```
console.clear();

const Client = require("./Structures/Client.js");

const config = require("./Data/config.json");

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const fs = require("fs");

fs.readdirSync("./src/Commands")
    .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"))
    .forEach((file) => {
        /**
         * @type {Command}
         */
        const commands = require(`./Commands/${file}`);
        console.log(`Command ${command.name} loaded`);
        client.commands.set(command.name, command);
    });

client.on("ready", () => console.log("SpidBot is online!"));

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    //console.log(message.content);
    //if (message.content == "!Spid") message.reply("Hello!");

    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;

    const args = message.content.substring(config.prefix.length).split(/ +/);

    const command = client.commands.find((cmd) => cmd.name == args[0]);
});

client.login(config.token);
```

can someone please explain why this happens and how I can fix it? btw I;m using node v16 (latest rn)

(heres my full folder, if you need it, and yes I DID change token after sending this: https://www.mediafire.com/folder/yrayh49wqgjfv/SpidBot

and the config.json https://www.mediafire.com/file/9gbhb5bazara5mp/config.json/file )

If I should send it using something else please tell me in the replies, Ty in advance

Comment: `const Discord = require("discord.js")`?

Comment: Where exactly do you expect the variable `Discord` to become defined in the code you provided?

Comment: Wdym? I'm sorry im just too new to programming and dont understand much

Comment: @Behemoth I added that but got another error https://srcb.in/8laWh7oY0W

Comment: At that point I'd recommend taking a look at JS basics and especially at the [Discord.js Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `discord.js` as it is an external library. In your console first you need to do

```
npm install discord.js@latest
```

The `@latest` is to make sure it is v13 as it seems that’s what you want to use

Then to import it, use `require`.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
```

Keep in mind you also need to import intents for v13

Comment: How do i do that? How do i import intents?

Comment: You need to do some research before trying to use discord.js. It’s in https://discordjs.guide

Comment: now i added the intents https://srcb.in/0FdnsMTuhZ but its telling me "ReferenceError: Intents is not defined"

Comment: it keeps giving me the same error even though i DID put the intents

Comment: Change it from `Intents.xxx` to `Discord.Intents.xxx`

Comment: Are you familiar with normal JavaScript? If you want to use discord.js, make sure you know normal JavaScript first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `Discord`.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js')
```

put this at the top of your file, make sure to install discord.js library by using `npm i discord.js` command in your terminal

Comment: I did that, now it says "identifier 'client' has already been declared"